# count number of elements in each group of data frame with a certain pattern from another data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm trying to count the number of elements from one group in  one data frame and assign it to another column in another data frame, based in some condition from one column in the second data frame.

This is my first data frame that I need to update:

```
node   name       count
1   aaa-1-1
1   trg-3-4-5 
2   bbb-2-2-4
3   ccc-3-3
```

This is the data frame that I'll use to count the values

```
node  name 
1   Empty-1-1-1  
1   Empty-1-1-2
1   Empty-1-1-3
2   gbn-2-3-5
3   Empty-3-3-9
```

I should filter from the name in df1 and count the number of elements in df1 that has the same id and has  the string 'EMPTY' and the 1-1 part of df1 so the output will look like

```
id   name       count
1   aaa-1-1    3
1   trg-3-4-5  0
2   bbb-2-2-4  0
3   ccc-3-3    1
```

To do that I appended both data frames and then grouped by id , and looped at each group, to get the count

```
        df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
       for _, gdf in df.groupby('node'):
            cds = gdf[gdf.name.str.count('-') == 2] 
            count_map = {}
            for i, c in cds.iterrows(): 
                k = c.name.split('-', 1)[-1] + '-'
                count_map[i] = gdf[gdf.name.str.contains('EMPTY-' + k)].shape[0]
            for kk, vv incount_map.items():
                df.loc[kk, 'count'] = vv
        return df
```

This functions works and get me the correct results but it takes very long time. I tried to merge both data frames and then count one column based on the other but the merging is not giving me the expected records, is there any way I could optimize this function

**EDIT :**

Having two data frames and searching between them is really expensive for huge datasets, So I used megred the to data frames and created daskdata frame where I grouped by 'node', now my search will be easier so what I have now is :

df_partioined a:

```
     node    name1        name2              count
       1 .    aaa-1-1 .     nan
       1 .    trg-3-4-5     nan
       1 .    nan           Empty-1-1-3
       1 .    nan .         Empty-1-1-1
       1      nan           Empty-1-1-2
```

Now at column name1 I'll filter out the names that contains Only tow dashes
so for this case will be 1-1, and then count number of elements that has this string

So my expected output will be

```
     node    name1        name2              count
       1 .    aaa-1-1 .     nan                  3
       1 .    trg-3-4-5     nan                  0
       1 .    nan           Empty-1-1-3          nan
       1 .    nan .         Empty-1-1-1          nan
       1      nan           Empty-1-1-2          nan
```

I splited the 1-1 into new column but not sure how I should do next :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df['count'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: df1['name'].str.contains(pd.Series(x).str.extract(r'(?:(\d-\d.*))$')[0][0]).sum())
```

output

```
   node       name  count
0     1    aaa-1-1      3
1     1  trg-3-4-5      0
2     2  bbb-2-2-4      0
3     3    ccc-3-3      1
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work because I have a huge data frame so what I have done is that I merged the two data frames and applied the function in every group, My question is not if I have to count the number of dashes from one column and if it is ==2  (e.x : tr-1-2) I  should count the number of `Empty-1-2` in the other column so it would be 'Empty'+pattern I got from the previous column .  Can you help me with that . Thanks a lot